# INSERT INTO `tab1` SELECT `tab2` put empty values when `tab2` doesn't have records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I would like to create an INSERT query, but like in the title - only when tab2 doesn't have records. Then query adds tab1 record with null values. I want to change it. When tab2 doesn't have records, the query doesn't add a record to tab1. How can I do it?

The Query currently looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tab1` (SELECT `id`, `value`, `another_value` FROM `tab2`);
```

Okay, i explain something more.

I have tab2, and if `tab2`.`status`=1 then this records will be copy to `tab1`. But if `tab2` doesn't have any records, then in `tab1` will add record, where `id` is next value than before `id` and other values is 0 or NULL. I wanna to change it, and if `tab2` doesn't have records, then query will not add empty record to `tab1`.

My real query is:

```
INSERT INTO `troops_support` (SELECT NULL AS `id`, `from`, `fromType`, `to`, `toType`, GROUP_CONCAT(`army` SEPARATOR ":") FROM `army_actions` WHERE `type`=0 AND (`start`+`duration`)<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: What do you mean? This is the default behavior. If `tab2` is empty, this query will add _zero_ records to `tab1`.

Comment: Dear geomagas - yes, and it's my problem. I wanna to add only not null values and find method, how can i do this.

Comment: _"when tab2 don't have records, then query add tab1 record with null values"_: No, this _will not happen with your query_. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: But query add record where id is next value than before and other fields is 0 or "". Sorry for my English.

Comment: geomagas is right. If table2 has no rows, then no rows at all will be inserted by this `INSERT..SELECT` statement.

Comment: @NewGuy: You'll have to explain that a little more. Preferably by editing your question.

Comment: Unless your query is not like this. Please add the query you use, don't change it.

Comment: Okay, i do it, now you have my real query. Thanks for your interest my problem.

Comment: Does this return 0? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM army_actions WHERE \`type\`=0 AND (\`start\`+duration)<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP();`

Comment: Ah never mind that. It's the `GROUP_CONCAT()` that makes this behaviour. All your rows are aggregated into 1 row, no matter if the table2 has a million or zero rows.

Comment: @ypercube - yes, this return 0

Comment: So i will check and use GROUP_CONCAT() if COUNT() will return more than 0?

Comment: You probably want to either totally remove the GROUP_CONCAT function or add a `GROUP BY` something in your query.

Comment: @ypercube - `GROUP BY` is working. Thanks a lot, write answer then i accept your answer

Comment: +1. @ypercube: You should do that. Since the problem was solved, there should be _at least one_ correct answer under this question -- someone might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thng like this:

```
If SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2 > 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_1
SELECT case when table_2_column_1 IS NOT NULL 
             THEN table_2_column_1
             else '' 
   END AS table_1_column1,
   case when table_2_column_2 IS NOT NULL 
             THEN table_2_column_2
             else '' 
   END AS table_1_column2
FROM table_2
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use IFNULL()

```
INSERT INTO `tab1` (SELECT IFNULL(`id`,''), IFNULL(`value`,''), IFNULL(`another_value`,'') FROM `tab2`);
```

Comment: It's working like your query, but i don't expect this result.

Comment: maybe you want to insert NULL instead of ''  for the blank ones